# Meaning of "S. Am."

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "S. Am." in this sentence from Reagan: "We have trouble, Cap & Bill Casey have views contrary to George's on S. Am., the Middle East & arms negotiations."

Comment: I would guess it's intended to mean "South America".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's short for "South America," as shown by a revised version in the book [Reagan's Secret War](https://books.google.com/books?id=IdZikhbzwEcC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> A long meeting with Secretary Shultz. We have trouble. Cap [Weinberger] and Bill Casey have views contrary to George's on South America, the Middle East & our arms negotiations. It's so out of hand George sounds like he wants out.